# Let $G$ be transitive.Then $\beta\in \operatorname{fix}(G_\alpha)$ implies $G_\alpha = G_\beta$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

i am new in this forum.

My question is about group actions

We have a transitive action of $G$ and $\beta$ a element in the fixed points of the stabilizer of another element $\alpha$. Then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have the same stabilizers?

Thank you for the further answers

Answer (score 1):

If it's finite groups you are talking about, then the following argument applies.

Your hypothesis is that $G_{\alpha} \le G_{\beta}$. Since $G$ acts transitively, there is $g \in G$ such that $\alpha g = \beta$, and then $g^{-1} G_{\alpha} g = G_{\beta}$.

If $G$ is finite, this implies that $G_{\alpha}$ and $G_{\beta}$ have the same order, so they are equal.

If $G$ is infinite, though, this isn't necessarily true. There are examples of groups $G$ with a subgroup $H$ and an element $g \in G$ such that *$H$ is properly contained in $g^{-1} H g$*. If you let $G$ act by right multiplication on the cosets $H a$, and take $\alpha = H$, $\beta = H g$, then $G_{\alpha} = H$ is properly contained in $G_{\beta} = g^{-1} G_{\alpha} g = g^{-1} H g$.

Comment: Ok thanks, my principal problem is give a bijection between the fixed points of a stabilizer of a point a and the lateral classes of the stabilizer of a in the normalizer of the stabilizer of a, and this conjecture appears, but I don't know a counter example specifically in stabilizers